# cakephp facebook component include paths on linux

Tags: linux, facebook, cakephp, path

I have a website on cakephp 1.3, with facebook integration. On my localhost(with windows os) it works fine, but on real hosting(with linux os) it gives this error `Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in /home/username/public_html/app/plugins/facebook/libs/f_b.php on line 22`.
This is f_b.php

```
App::import('Vendor', 'Facebook.facebook/src/facebook');
App::import('Lib', 'Facebook.FacebookInfo');
class FB {

  /**
    * Facebook Api
    */
  public static $Facebook = null;

  public function __construct() {
    if (empty(self::$Facebook)) {
            self::$Facebook = new Facebook(FacebookInfo::getConfig()); }  // 22 line
  }
```

so, apparently it can not load Vender, I think there is a problem with paths, though this does not work either `App::import('Vendor', 'Facebook.facebook'.DS.'src'.DS.'facebook');`

`f_b.php` located in `plugins/facebook/libs/` folder and this `Facebook.php` vendor is located in `plugins/facebook/vendors/facebook/src` folder

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution of my problem, in order to work both on windows and linux it is necessary write like this

```
App::import('Vendor', 'Facebook.Facebook', array('file' => 'facebook/src/Facebook.php' ));
```

Here, are couple of example for that - [Vendor examples](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Configuration.html#vendor-examples)

Answer (score 0):

I’d say your paths don’t look right (why is there a dot?).

When I’ve used plugins with CakePHP, I’ve had to enable them by un-commenting the `Plugins::loadAll()` line in **app/config/bootstrap.php**. This will then make my library available in my CakePHP application.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but isn't it new in cake 2 (`Plugins::loadAll()`)? .  About dot, it was in plugin, I haven't made any changes, and on windows everything is ok

Comment: Yeah, `Plugins::loadAll()` is CakePHP 2.0+. However, I’m still concerned that there’s dots in your file paths for the Facebook SDK location? Shouldn’t the second value just be the path to your plugin?